# How to determine base name of Emacs buffer file name?

Tags: emacs

Assume I edit in Emacs a file `t.txt` in my home directory. Then
`ESC-: buffer-file-name` produces `/Home/fcihh/t.txt` How can I extract the file name part `t.txt` from that?

According to [this link](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Components.html) I thought I should be able to write
`ESC-: (file-name-base buffer-file-name)`. But this produces the error

```
Lisp error: (void-function file-name-base)
```

I am using GNU Emacs 23.3.1 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately `file-name-base` has been introduced in Emacs 24.  Here is its definition, from [`lisp/files.el`](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/trunk/annotate/head:/lisp/files.el):

```
(defun file-name-base (&optional filename)
  "Return the base name of the FILENAME: no directory, no extension.
FILENAME defaults to `buffer-file-name'."
  (file-name-sans-extension
   (file-name-nondirectory (or filename (buffer-file-name)))))
```

Both `file-name-sans-extension` and `file-name-nondirectory` should be available in Emacs 23.

If you want the base name with extension you only need `file-name-nondirectory`.